# What is the best way to store large session data in web applications?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web-applications, flask

I am building a website that does not require people to login, but still needs large session data.

Example: a person uploads a 0.5 MB file. I want to able to manipulate this this from now and then. Where should I store it? I would prefer something like a cookie system, but obviously this is too small. Redis seems like an opportunity, but I was hoping for something simpler.

I'm using Python flask.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Redis is pretty simple. I'm using it in an app I'm running and it works pretty good aside from some weirdness (https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py). However I don't see why a file should be kept inside the session. Any particualar reason for that ?

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

- Have the person upload the file(s) to the server.  In this case you will not want to store the file in the session - instead, you will want to store a reference to the file's location in their session (or persist it somewhere more permanent if they need to be able to come back with a new session and still work with the old file).

  ```
  @app.route("/upload", methods=["GET", "POST"])
  def upload_file():
      # Create a folder in your uploads section to store
      # this user's files.
      # Store the file in it (use werkzeug.security.safe_join
      # to ensure the file name is safe).
      # Add the *safe* file name to the session
      # or the datastore (e. g. a database)
      # so you can look it up later
  ```
- Use the new DOM Filesystem API to store the files on the client side so they never come to your server and manipulate the files with JavaScript.

The pros of the first method are that you can store large files and manipulate them with many different tools (not just Python).  The cons are that you have to store the files and make sure to sanitize the file names (to avoid having the server hacked).

The pros of the second method are that you don't need to store anything on the server (so you don't have to pay for extra storage).  The cons are that you are likely to be limited in the amount of data you can store, and you only have access to libraries that run in a browser (i. e. JS only) *or* you have to pass all of the data over to your server when you need to do something more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Yuo should try localstorage  .

Answer (score 0):

May be you need [memcached](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memcached). It's simpler than Redis.